# How come my onMouseOver effect is not working?

Tags: javascript, function, for-loop, dom-events

As the title states, my `onMouseOver` event listener is not working. I'm able to create a 'hover' pseudo class in CSS and have it work that way but I want to create an event listener for this to work.

Code:

```
let container = document.getElementById('container');

//function to create 16x16 grid
function gridSquares () {

  for (x = 0; x < 256; x++) {
    let squares = document.createElement('div');
    squares.className = 'grid-square';
    container.appendChild(squares);

    //mouse-over event listener for each grid
    squares.addEventListener('onmouseover', function () {
      const gridSquare = document.getElementsByClassName('grid-square');

      gridSquare.setAttribute('style', 'background: yellow');
    });

  }
}

gridSquares();
```

I've created a div in my HTML with an ID of 'container' as well.

Any ideas?

Comment: Remove "on". State it as `mouseover`. The "on" bit is for inline declaration of the event. And I see @JackyShows mentions below as well.

Comment: ^^ Thanks bud, I completely missed that, it works now!

Comment: Use your browser’s dev tools and look for errors on the console. For example getElementsByClassName returns a collection of elements, not a single element.

Comment: True @AHaworth. How is OP code even working. As you mention, `gridSquare` would be a collection. How does OP circumvent this. Might be a case of just saying it works? Lol. The world.

Comment: Hey guys - I realized that as well and I changed up the code.

changed it to just 'squares.style.cssText = 'background: yellow'; in that event listener. I just used the variable from above since its within the for loop.

Btw - I am a newb lol. Working on an Odin assignment

Comment: Well @AlbertYoo if you changing your code and not updating here as well: Expect comments to read as above.

Comment: @GetSet - I updated it after I posted the question haha. Btw - I should prob ask another question about this but since we're here, would it be possible to add multiple event handlers/listeners to an element?

I'd like the color to change once its clicked, then if its moved over it will change. Basically, the click will start it off and then can be dragged over the other squares to change colors. 

If this makes sense. I appreciate yours and the above commenters help!!

Comment: Actually on *really* looking at your code @AlbertYoo, and as @AHaworth mentions, how in the world do you treat a collection as an element and it works, e.g. `document.getElementsByClassName`

Comment: No AlbertYoo it doesnt work like that. @JackyShows solved your event problem and you didnt even have the courtesy to accept that answer. No, you cant tack on new issues. Am voting to close since you cant acknowledge help, must mean its misguided real question.

Comment: You say you used squares as it’s in the for loop, but by the time it comes to be executed in the event handler what does squares refer to? You may like to read up about event handling and the use of the event object.to help you refer to the square that has been mousedover.

Comment: @GetSet How do I 'accept the answer'? I didnt know that was a thing - being 100% honest

Comment: @GetSet - I found out how to accept the answer. Sorry - I didnt know that. I'm going to have to accept other answers from previously answered questions. Thnx for bringing to my awareness

Comment: @AHaworth On each new instantiation of `squares`, the `squares` will be a new and distinct object, i think. The `let` is just for scoping. There should be a new and distinct `squares` per iteration of the loop, as written in OP's code.

Comment: @GetSet - correct, I'd misread the code. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty sure is not

```
squares.addEventListener('onmouseover', function() {...
```

but is:

```
squares.addEventListener('mouseover', function() {...
```

You should remove 'on' inside the event listener